# WP7 - Add Authentication to Push Notifications

Tags: asp.net, windows-phone-7, push-notification, mpns

I am looking to add authentication to my WP7 application. I currently have simple, unauthorized push notifications working thanks to [this MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202967%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

I am having difficulty figuring out exactly what I need to change in my code in order to get authentication. I have read [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941099%28VS.92%29.aspx) and know I need to get a TLS certificate uploaded to the App Dev website (in progress) and get some info from it once it's verified.

Thanks for reading/helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean code to change in your WP application, you shouldn't have to change anything. Authentication simply changes the way your web service communicates with the Microsoft Push Notification Service, rather than how the Microsoft Push Notification Service communicates with your app on the phone.